# Including JS into webpage

Tags: 7, theming, javascript, hooks

I'm trying to use a small piece of JS code in my site (D7).
The code should automatically insert a guid to an `<input>` field with "my-input" ID on page and set this field to "readonly", like this

```
<input id="my-input" type="text" readonly size="40">
```

The script guid.js looks like this

```
function guid() {
  return s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4();
}

function s4() {
  return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
    .toString(16)
    .substring(1);
}

document.getElementById("my-input").value = guid();
```

I've tried to include the file, also with "inline" methods but cannot get it work.

My I ask you for your advice how to do it? I will need also to specify, in which files to make the changes as I'm a Drupal newbie.
On the website, OG and PURL are also implemented if this can influence something.

Comment: Meanwhile, I get it work. It looks that the problem was the javascript was in header. After putting it to the footer, it works. This is meaningful that the form must be created and fill the values at the end. I found an usefull module for injecting the JS into drupal called JS Injector [link](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector). Making the input read-only, follow this guide [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/74824)

Comment: Best use jQuery and ready() method and you will avoid this kind of problems.